# VSCODE. Como decirle al plugin Emmet que en los ficheros .twig use snnipets de html y css

Tags: vscode, extensiones

en mi fichero `settings.json` de vscode, tengo la siguiente configuracion para **emmet** en ficheros twig:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "twig": "html"
},
```

Ahora en los ficheros twig reconoce html, pero tambien quisiera que reconozca el css, como puedo decirle que en los ficheros **twig** incorpore tanto  **html** como **CSS**

Comment: De acuerdo a [esto](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62910) no es posible. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras cierto, muchas gracias. Me extraña muchisimo que algo asi no soporte multi-lenguaje. Gracias !